# Finding the complimentary "If" statement for the "Else" statement in tibco

Tags: sql, tibco

So, I'm debugging a huge Tibco query statement creator in a DB query  with what seems to be a million concats with if then, else if then, else statements. I've broken it down 3/4 of the way to the query that should be generated based on my input, then came across a random else and I'm not sure which if it comes from, since there's no enclosing brackets like in java (if () {   }). I think I might have found it, but I'm not sure because from my understanding a if can either have a else statement or no else based on how the statement was constructed ( right click and surround by doesn't need an else). Any ideas on how to figure out which if statements it is coming from??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Pasting the query in IntelliJ allowed me to see where the parenthesis to each concat statement ends, unlike notepad ++, which didn't seemed to recognize the closing parenthesis unless it was in the same line.

Comment: I am using the online SQL-Formater http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm to understand the SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just pasted it in there to see how it would compare, but my statement is so long (due to tibco's structuring) that it was slightly less than a 3rd of the entire length of statement, which didn't help me much because I was about 3/4 of the way. Thanks for the input though, I'll totally test this out for other statements.